# Qquery to fetch the data in the required format in SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I have some columns as shown below,

```
1st Month   2nd Month   3rd Month   4th Month   5th Month   6th Month   Current_Month
10          20          30          40          50          60          70
10          10          10          10          10          10          10
```

And i need output like this,

```
Feb March   April   May June    July    August
10  20      30      40  50      60      70
10  10      10      10  10      10      10
```

And the data varies every month, So current month column should be replaced by the Name of the Month and accordingly the last months data with Names of the month.

Please note i'm a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your query that returned sample output given above

Comment: This design smells... Is this *SQL-Server table data* or some strange Excel-Import? In general: Dynamic column headers need dynamic SQL or (with limits) pivot. Both concepts are not really beginner's stuff... Please give more details...

Comment: Believe me guys i'm a real beginner and given this task by heads, and  i don't have any query's available with me to get any sample output this one.

Comment: It's been one day and i didn't get any help.. Guys is anyone can do this ?